# Docker pull failed to unpack image on snapshotter stargz: mismatched image rootfs and manifest layers

Tags: docker, macos

I'm facing the following error on macOS using Docker Desktop (ARM architecture):

```
docker pull ghcr.io/xxx/yyy
failed to unpack image on snapshotter stargz: mismatched image rootfs and manifest layers
```

The docker image was created with gorelease and the following section kos build section:

```
# https://ko.build/
kos:
  - repository: ghcr.io/xxx/yyy
    tags:
      - '{{.Tag}}'
      - '{{ if not .Prerelease }}latest{{ end }}'
    bare: true
    preserve_import_paths: false
    sbom: none
    platforms:
      - all
    flags:
      - -trimpath
    ldflags:
      - -s -w
```

So, I would like to understand the root of the issue, is it mismatch of architecture(s), i.e. image contains amd64 while is installing on arm64, or any other issue. According to ko.build the platform all should build images on all architectures, but I don't know how I check this. According to build GitHUb action build I saw that arm build was there, but does image has it I do not know. And, I do not know if it is issue of docker desktop, ko.build, gorelease, or anything else. Any advice would be helpful.